# Why is there a difference in the results of both the for loops?

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop

Both of the for loops are the exact same but i dont understand why the first for loop isnt working.

```
t = [[1,0],[2,0]]
z =  [[1,0],[2,0]]
for i in t:
    i = [x for x in i if x!=0]
for i in range(len(z)):
    z[i] = [x for x in z[i] if x!=0]
print(t)
print(z)
```

Output:

[[1, 0], [2, 0]]

[[1], [2]]

Comment: can you explain what you expect to get?

Comment: One of the reasons why its not working is because you are not assigning anything to `t` in the first for loop. So `t` doesn't change.

Comment: @Ouroborus **absolutely incorrect**. It definitely gives you the object itself for all built-in containers, and for pretty much any container you might work with that implements iteration, with perhaps a few exceptions, but definitely not here

Comment: "Both of the for loops are the exact same " No, they are not the same at all.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, I realized it's because they're assigning to the temp variable which, of course, doesn't affect the original list. (Then there's to whole thing of not being allowed to modify a list that you're iterating over.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first loop is just overwriting the temporary variable `i` rather than writing that data back to the array.

```
for i in t:
    # saves data back to loop variable i 
    i = [x for x in i if x!=0]
for i in range(len(z)):
    # saves data to this index in array z
    z[i] = [x for x in z[i] if x!=0]
```

When you assign a new value to `i`, you don't change the data that `i` originally referred to (the data in the array `t`). Instead, you cause `i` to refer to the new data. The array remains unchanged unless you change it explicitly - like you do in the second loop.

Comment: @teja - You're very welcome!